# How to externally trigger [neo]vim to reload an edited file?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, autocmd

I have a file, `/tmp/file.txt` that is being edited by `vim` (or `neovim`), as well as some other external process.

I wish the external app to notify `vim`, in such a way that `vim` takes that notification to reload the file.

Any kind of external hooks?  To let other external apps tell `vim` *"hey, you may want to do something now"*?

The reason I ask this, is because [`autoread` doesn't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490227/how-does-vims-autoread-work/2490635#2490635).

Comment: You can use `checktime` periodically from an autocmd or timer to have Vim check the external file for modifications periodically. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428958/9447571) and the one below it, for example. It's not exactly what you're looking for (notification from external source), but I believe it should solve your actual issue.

Comment: I hadn't tested, but if you run vim as client server, you may be able to do this with `--remote-expr`.

Comment: It depends on the OS, but you can simulate a sequence of key presses sent to vim. Another option would be subscription to event using builtin python. I assume that it won't stuck neovim at least. Another idea, open a terminal or execute with `:! ` a task that would exit at the right time.